# How add new rows to model when using NGX-DataTable with NGX-Formly

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable, ngx-formly

Using Formly I've implemented a solution similiar to the one found here:
https://formly.dev/examples/advanced/datatable-integration

This works for displaying existing data, the issue occurs when trying to add  new rows. I need a way to update the FormGroup list, I've spoofed this currently by adding the first row again. Visually it looks right, but it would always be binding to the wrong row.

```
     var newRow = this.fields[1].fieldGroup[0];
     this.fields[1].fieldGroup.push(newRow);
```

I have an example here (modified version of above example):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/formly-add-ngxdatatablerow?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pointed to this link by Abdellatif Ait boudad which resolved my issue:
https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/issues/2250#issuecomment-630577383

Instead of just pushing to the array, I also had set the model in order for Formly to detect the change.

```
      this.model.investments.push({});
      this.model = { ...this.model, investments: this.model.investments };
```

This will add a new row to my table, and bind it correctly.